How could the Sages suppress such sefarim such as Yechezkel and Kohelet?
They of course seemed to have had good intentions so as to not let the books confuse people but how is it possible that some of the most wise and humble men decide that they have the right to suppress Yechezkel which has the word of Hashem and Kohelet which was written by someone who had been confirmed to have so much wisdom and possibly the most of any human ever? How can they think that they are more wise than the ones who have been confirmed as wise by Hashem? Regarding Kohelet for example they allowed to keep it because it began and ended with Torah. What if it didn't? If Shlomo thought that people should learn it then how could they as humble men think that they were smarter than him in allowing people to learn it? That is amplified regarding the word of Hashem in Yechezkel.

How could they do it to ben sira?

@DoubleAA -- The commentators excluded Ben Sira (Ecclesisticus)  because it shows Epicurean and Sadducean tendencies.  However, the Talmud says: "Rabbi Yosef said: [We may ban the book as a whole, yet still] we may expound to [the masses] the good things that the book contains." [Sanhedrin 100b; also Bava Kamma 92b].

@DoubleAA ben sira didn't hear the word of Hashem as is the case of Yechezkel, and he wasn't confirmed as very wise by Hashem as is the case of Shlomo. One might make an argument for him but I don't see how they can for these two.

@Shamir how do you know that

In I Kings 3: 12 Hashem gives Shlomo a lot of wisdom, regarding Yechezkel it's pretty evident that he's claiming Hashem spoke to him and that he should relay this information to Bnei Yisrael which the sages obviously agree is a good claim. I'm not familiar with ben sira, does he say that Hashem spoke to him and wants him to relay information, is there another text the says that Hashem gave him wisdom?

@Shamir -- No, I don't think any of the Apocrypha were intended as prophetic.  But they could have been candidates for Ketuvim, if not Neviim.

The rabbis had to make decisions in the face of mountains of candidate books.  Most were rejected for inclusion in the Tanakh because they had secular or Hellenistic tendencies, or disagreed with the Torah in some of their statements, or were deemed to be fictional, or were not written in Hebrew, or were not Jewish, or were too recent, or did not add new teachings, etc.  Most had the name of God in them.  Many, if not most, are lost as a result.
In question were The Song of Songs (no mention of God, too erotic), Ecclesiastes (self-contradictory), Esther (no mention of God), Proverbs (self-contradictory), Job (fictional), Ezekiel (contradicts Torah), etc.  The discussions that resulted in their acceptance are in the Talmud [Yadayim 3:5, Shabbat 30b, Megillah 7a, Bava Batra 15a].

I'm not sure how that answers the question. How can humble and wise men think that they have the right to suppress books that they view as having the wrong tendencies when the books were written by men who have been confirmed to have the word of Hashem or being a very wise man by Hashem himself. None of the Rabbis have had Hashem confirm that they are very wise or that they have the word of Hashem (not that they aren't very wise, I think they were).

Maybe they didn't believe these books had "the word of Hashem" in them.  Just because a book began with "The words of ___, who prophesied concerning ___" doesn't mean they had to believe it.

is it possible that the sages didn't think that Yechezkel didn't have "the word of Hashem" in them? That brings forth many more problems than the one it tried to patch up.
